# Get counts of UNIQUE records OVERALL per value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

This is related to the question below:
[split records into buckets based on a sum of counts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23023283/split-records-into-buckets-based-on-a-sum-of-counts)

The new problem is that one person can have many faxes, and since I'm trying to get a certain number of people: I usually end up with less than I need, because the same people land in more than one faxbucket

Is there a way to get a count of UNIQUE people in the attached example?

here's my table, it's called NR_PVO_120

```
OtherID     Fax
12365092    2762364204
12005656    2762364204
12484936    2762364204
39003042    2762364204
12365597    2762364204
12635922    2762364204
12332346    2762364204
12365092    4387267572
12005656    4387267572
12365092    4422911281
12005656    4422911281
12484936    4422911281
12651239    4422911281
12388710    4422911281
12686953    4422911281
12365092    4423311213
12005656    4423311213
12709544    4423311213
12484936    4423311213
12005656    4424450542
12346839    4424450542
12365120    4424450542
12484936    4424450542
12086512    4424450542
```

Based on this table i create a query that's used in the function linked using the following query

```
SELECT   Fax
     ,COUNT(OtherID) CountOfPracs
    FROM NR_PVO_120
GROUP BY Fax
```

So the counts would look like this

```
Fax         CountOfPeople
4422911281  6
4387267572  2
4423311213  4
4424450542  5
2762364204  7
```

If you add up all counts you're getting 24 people but in reality there are only 14 because one person can have multiple faxes.

is there a way to only count those people for the second fax that don't weren't counted in the first one. then for the 3rd fax only count those that weren't counted in the first two and so on?

so the results would be

```
2762364204  7
4387267572  0
4422911281  3
4423311213  1
4424450542  3

the first fax has 7 people 
the second fax has 2 but both of those were already counted in the first fax so no new unique people were added
the third fax has 4 but only 1 of those hasn't already been counted 
the fourth fax has 5 but only 1 hasn't been counted earlier 
the fifth fax has 7 but only 3 weren't counted earlier
```

i know this isn't the way to create counts, they're not correct data wise but that's OK. i'm just trying to get all the fax numbers that have a certain number of people. let's say i need 10 people, i have to pick out that 10 but at the same time make sure that all the fax numbers stay together. if you look at my NR_PVO_120 table and look at the first 10 people you see that the 9th starts another fax number that spreads until 11. i won't take that fax. i ether find a fax with 1 person attached or, if there are none, i stop at 9. the point is to get 10 people but make sure all people with the same fax are grouped together.

or is there some other way to only count the UNIQUE providers (which should equal to 14)?

Comment: Please post the relevant details (data, queries, etc.) in **this** question.  The other question was already answered.

Comment: What means "one person can have 2 phone numbers"? Two rows in the table `test_data` with the same AutoID? I can't see difference with previous question.

Comment: sorry, i didn't explain it right. i just added an EDIT at the bottom with an example

Comment: I had written an answer, but it was wrong. Now I need to go to sleep, but tomorrow I'll try to answer again.

Comment: i saw :) i started trying to put it together and couldn't follow one part, was just about to reply and then it disappeared. thank you for even trying))))

Comment: I still don't understand question. In table with columns `personid` and `phone` you have 4 unique PersonID's and 4 unique phone numbers. After that you receive table (last one in your post) where sum of all numbers in column `CountOfPeople` is 6. You want to say, that 6 is wrong, you need sum just 4 (`1` in every row)?

Comment: yes, exactly. how do i query like this? i'm adding another EDIT

Comment: basically, when i put the number inside the function "select * from table(get_buckets(130));" (130 in this case) that number should be the count of UNIQUE providers, not the sum of the countsOfPeople because that number will be almost always inflated

Comment: Jon, which tag do you use to make code look this way? also, i solved this problem in excel, is it OK to post even though this was an oracle q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the table for testing:

```
create table nr_pvo_120 (
   otherid,
   fax
)
as
select 12365092    , 2762364204 from dual union all
select 12005656    , 2762364204 from dual union all
select 12484936    , 2762364204 from dual union all
select 39003042    , 2762364204 from dual union all
select 12365597    , 2762364204 from dual union all
select 12635922    , 2762364204 from dual union all
select 12332346    , 2762364204 from dual union all
select 12365092    , 4387267572 from dual union all
select 12005656    , 4387267572 from dual union all
select 12365092    , 4422911281 from dual union all
select 12005656    , 4422911281 from dual union all
select 12484936    , 4422911281 from dual union all
select 12651239    , 4422911281 from dual union all
select 12388710    , 4422911281 from dual union all
select 12686953    , 4422911281 from dual union all
select 12365092    , 4423311213 from dual union all
select 12005656    , 4423311213 from dual union all
select 12709544    , 4423311213 from dual union all
select 12484936    , 4423311213 from dual union all
select 12005656    , 4424450542 from dual union all
select 12346839    , 4424450542 from dual union all
select 12365120    , 4424450542 from dual union all
select 12484936    , 4424450542 from dual union all
select 12086512    , 4424450542 from dual
/
```

My first shot would be: For each person (otherid) get his *first* fax number only and then do a normal group by and count on that:

```
select first_fax, count(*) firstcount
  from (
   select otherid, min(fax) first_fax
     from nr_pvo_120
    group by otherid
       )
 group by first_fax
 order by first_fax
/
```

The output will become:

```
 FIRST_FAX FIRSTCOUNT
---------- ----------
2762364204          7
4422911281          3
4423311213          1
4424450542          3
```

Then I noticed your desired output included the fifth fax number but with a count of zero. That can for example be done like this:

```
select fax, count(*) normalcount, count(otherid_on_first_fax) countunused
  from (
   select fax, otherid,
          case
             when fax = min(fax) over (partition by otherid order by fax)
             then otherid
          end otherid_on_first_fax
     from nr_pvo_120
       )
 group by fax
 order by fax
/
```

In this output, column `NORMALCOUNT` is the number of people having that fax. Column `COUNTUNUSED` is the number of people that haven't already been *"used"* in the previous counts:

```
       FAX NORMALCOUNT COUNTUNUSED
---------- ----------- -----------
2762364204           7           7
4387267572           2           0
4422911281           6           3
4423311213           4           1
4424450542           5           3
```

The trick is that `otherid_on_first_fax` only has the value of `otherid` on the persons first fax number, for the rest of the persons fax numbers `otherid_on_first_fax` is NULL. `count(otherid_on_first_fax)` then counts all the non-null values, of which there are none for fax 4387267572.

Comment: no, it doesn't have to be 0, that was just one way i thought of doing it. but i can't believe you got this done in oracle!!!!! thank you very much.

Comment: hey, sorry, both your answers are correct, Dmitry answered first though. and you both gave two options. i wish i can split the bounty, i'm never sure what to do in these cases, it seems unfair.

Comment: Deleted, will repost later

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now I understand.

One person can have many numbers, but in result table we see numbers, not persons. So the question is - what is the rule to define that? If it doesn't matters:

```
SQL> with t as (
  select 12365092 OtherID, 2762364204 Fax from dual union all
  select 12005656, 2762364204 from dual union all
  select 12484936, 2762364204 from dual union all
  select 39003042, 2762364204 from dual union all
  select 12365597, 2762364204 from dual union all
  select 12635922, 2762364204 from dual union all
  select 12332346, 2762364204 from dual union all
  select 12365092, 4387267572 from dual union all
  select 12005656, 4387267572 from dual union all
  select 12365092, 4422911281 from dual union all
  select 12005656, 4422911281 from dual union all
  select 12484936, 4422911281 from dual union all
  select 12651239, 4422911281 from dual union all
  select 12388710, 4422911281 from dual union all
  select 12686953, 4422911281 from dual union all
  select 12365092, 4423311213 from dual union all
  select 12005656, 4423311213 from dual union all
  select 12709544, 4423311213 from dual union all
  select 12484936, 4423311213 from dual union all
  select 12005656, 4424450542 from dual union all
  select 12346839, 4424450542 from dual union all
  select 12365120, 4424450542 from dual union all
  select 12484936, 4424450542 from dual union all
  select 12086512, 4424450542 from dual)
select mx, count(otherid) 
  from (select otherid, max(fax) mx 
          from t
         group by otherid)
 group by mx; 

        MX COUNT(OTHERID)
---------- --------------
4423311213      2
4424450542      5
2762364204      4
4422911281      3
```

If you need to define the order of numbers, you can use this:

```
SQL> with t as (<see previous example>)
select fax, count(otherid)
  from (select fax, otherid, row_number() over (partition by otherid order by fax) rn
          from t)
 where rn = 1
 group by fax;

       FAX COUNT(OTHERID)
---------- --------------
4423311213      1
4424450542      3
2762364204      7
4422911281      3
```

`order by` inside the analytical function defines, which phones will be displayed in result.

Comment: lol, not that easy. it shows 1 for every line. some phone numbers will have 20 people attached to it, 1 will just count rows essentially. there has to be a way to count unique providers inside the function. i will play with it for a while and will put a bounty on it if i don't get anywhere

Comment: i just added this in the original question. is there a way to only count those people for the second phone number that don't weren't counted in the first one. then for the 3rd phone number only count those that weren't counted in the first two and so on?

Comment: @lalachka Wait, let's start from beginning once again. Could you edit your post (or start another one) and write following: 1) your source table (with `PERSONID` and `PHONE`) 2) your second table (`AutoID`, `PHONE`, `Count_of_people`) - how it MUST look 3) your query to transform table 1 to table 2. Because I am not sure that I understood the problem yet. 1) and 2) you had already done. Also, you don't need a code from your previous question, link is sufficient.

Comment: sure and i'm adding a bounty so it's worth your while (i can only add it in a half hour though). i also thought link is sufficient but OldProgrammer said to post everything in this question as well. i will edit it now

Comment: hey, i just edited some more, adding a bounty now, let me know if i still didn't explain it well enough. sorry, i'm not good at explaining things

Comment: sorry, i wish i can split the bounty. both your answers work but Kim did it two ways. even though i don't think it matters to me which way to do it, it's nice to have options once i start implementing it. it might turn out that taking the min or max won't work for me but it will be days before i know. thank you and sorry

Comment: i just realized you gave the other option as well, it's a little diff from mine, trying to see what it does. sorry, i hate this part, where i have to decide between two answers so i keep switching back and forth

Comment: it doesn't work. the solution i gave was wrong, so probably that's why. how do i get 10 people from my list while keeping the fax numbers together? i thought i can do it by only counting unused faxes but no, once it's plugged into your function it stop working because the faxes get rearranged. i will open a new question, this one is a mess but i'm awarding the bounty to you anyway, i just asked the question wrong